# File is empty after creating it using Uri - Retrofit

Tags: java, android, file, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a file using Uri. But when it is checked whether its empty, it   is found empty. Below is the code where the Uri is stored in the variable "**filePath**".

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();                
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So i have created a function to upload the file to server using retrofit library.
On button click the function is called. Below is the code:

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {

        String descriptionString = "hello";
        File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());

        if(file.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,file.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,file.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                        file
                );

        MultipartBody.Part image =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

        Call<ImageResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().uploadImage(descriptionString,image);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ImageResponse> call, Response<ImageResponse> response) {
                ImageResponse imageResponse = response.body();
                if (imageResponse.isError())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imageResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imageResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

So my request is failing because the file doesn't exist. What could be the reason? I'm using emulator and have added all the required permissions. I have no idea why it shouldn't work. Please help me! I'm new to retrofit.

My Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And the final response I'm getting in toast is:

> document/image:31 (no such file or directory )

Comment: Did you forget to ask the user for dangerous permissions in runtime?

Comment: `fileUri.getPath()` - this will not work - you cannot get the "file path" like that

Comment: Then what is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that no matter you specify permissions in Manifest, you have to check the permissions at runtime from Android v6.0. So all you have to do is check permissions at run time.

Here is the code. Use the below code:

```
//Check Permissions on runtime
    public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(
            final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        (Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    showDialog("External storage", context,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat
                            .requestPermissions(
                                    (Activity) context,
                                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(final String msg, final Context context,
                           final String permission) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
        alertBuilder.setMessage(msg + " permission is necessary");
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                new String[] { permission },
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // do your stuff
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GET_ACCOUNTS Denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                        grantResults);
        }
    }
    //End permission code

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            try {
                if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)) {
                    filePath=data.getData();
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),filePath);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {

        String descriptionString = "hello";
        File file=FileUtils.getFile(getApplicationContext(),fileUri);

        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                        file
                );

        MultipartBody.Part image =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

        Call<ImageResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().uploadImage(descriptionString,image);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ImageResponse> call, Response<ImageResponse> response) {
                ImageResponse imageResponse = response.body();
                if (imageResponse.isError())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imageResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,imageResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is the FileUtils class:

```
public class FileUtils {

    //replace this with your authority
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents";


    private FileUtils() {
    } //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

    /**
     * TAG for log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // Set to true to enable logging


    /**
     * @return Whether the URI is a local one.
     */
    public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static boolean isLocalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
     * <br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see #isLocal(String)
     * @see #getFile(Context, Uri)
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {


        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Convert Uri into File, if possible.
     *
     * @return file A local file that the Uri was pointing to, or null if the
     * Uri is unsupported or pointed to a remote resource.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see #getPath(Context, Uri)
     */
    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```